# Fast query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a very large database (~1TB), so running even a very simple query can take a very long time. Eg. for:

```
EXPLAIN select count(*) from users;
```

the cost is 44661683.87 disk page fetch. Hence making it very expensive to execute. 
When I try to put a limit on the query like:

```
EXPLAIN select count(*) from users limit 10;
```

the cost of executing the query remains the same i.e 44661683.87 disk page fetch.

So (1) is it possible to execute a query on subset of data and then extrapolate to the rest of the table? The row size can be quickly found using something like:

```
SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'users';
```

Moreover, (2) is it possible to select a randomly distributed subset of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to execute a query on subset of data and then extrapolate to the rest of the table

You could use the `tablesample` option:

```
select count(*) * 10
from the_table tablesample system (10);
```

`tablesample system (10)` will only scan 10 percent of the blocks of the table which should be quite fast. If you multiply the resulting row count with 10 you'll have an approximation(!) of the total number of rows. The smaller the sample size is the faster, this will be - but also less accurate.

I accuracy of the number depends on how much free space your table has because the 10% (or whatever sample size you choose) is based on the total number of blocks in the table. If there are many free (or half free) blocks, then the number will be less reliable.

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*) . . .` is an aggregation query with no `group by`.  It returns 1 row, so the limit has no impact.

You seem to want:

```
select count(*)
from (select u.*
      from users u
      limit 10
     );
```

As for your second question, Postgres introduced `tablesample` in version 9.5.  [You can investigate that.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a primary key index on the users table (or an index on another column), you can get it to use that index for an index-only scan which should result in a much better execution plan.  But, strangely, it won't work with COUNT so you can do a SELECT DISTINCT in a subquery and then COUNT on an outer query to force it to use the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users) u;
```

Comment: That won't change anything. Postgres will scan the PK index for a `count(*)` anyway

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I just ran EXPLAIN on for SELECT COUNT(*) on a very large table in PG 9.6 and it is showing Seq Scan on the table, not the index.

Comment: The index only scan is subject to up-to-date statistics and a properly vacuumed table - but I do see that for nearly all my tables. Something like this: https://explain.depesz.com/s/HA5